# Mouse coordinates irrelevant after zooming, is it bug?

Tags: three.js

I have a problem about getting the mouse coordinates, it behaves irrelevant after zooming.

I have a JS fiddle link of my code, it will show what the problem I face, is it bug in `three.js` or the way I approach to draw a line is wrong, please give your feedback.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/ceej4jxq/1/

```
var elem = self.renderer.domElement,
                boundingRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
                x = (e.clientX - boundingRect.left) * (elem.width / boundingRect.width),
                y = (e.clientY - boundingRect.top) * (elem.height / boundingRect.height);
var vector = new THREE.Vector3((x / $("container").width()) * 2 - 1, -(y / $("container").height()) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
var pos = projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

var dir = pos.clone().sub(camera.position).normalize().multiplyScalar(-1);
var distance = camera.position.z / dir.z;     
var pos1 = camera.position.clone().sub(dir.multiplyScalar(distance));
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: line seems to still draw correctly when I zoom in. What is your problem?

Comment: did u check zoom out? do some large zoom.

Comment: ahh yes, zooming out creates a problem

Comment: is it bug? or any other way is there to get mouse coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your camera `near` plane in your fiddle is 0.0001, and your camera `far` plane is 10,000,000,000.

Consequently, you are having numerical problems in your code when you call `unprojectVector()`.

The issue is closely related to the depth buffer precision problems described here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer_Precision.

Set your near plane to 1, or greater,  and your far plane to the smallest value you can get away with, say 10000.

three.js r.68

Comment: i accept the answer, but i feel its a partial output, for now.