# THREE.js Jittering/Shaking Vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js, precision, shake, jitter

I'm building a tiled slippy map globe in THREE.js much like [Cesium](https://cesiumjs.org/). The issue I've run into is that when, at high zoom levels, I rotate the Perspective/OrbitControls camera, the **tiles jitter/shake**. It's probably a precision issue but I don't know how to work around this one.

**How I'm projecting tiles:**

- Create a THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry centered at the origin of the
  parent planet (an Object3D at (0, -planetRadius, 0) ).
- Project each of the plane's attribute vertices (one by one) to a point matching it's correct latitude, longitude and elevation (lonLatToVector3()).
- I then have a camera that can zoom in on a plane/tile and the
  distance from the camera to the tile determines which zoom level
  tiles to render.

**Things that don't solve the issue:**

- A near clipping plane of 1.
- A close far clipping range (such as near: 1, far: 2).
- A logarthmic or non-logarthmic depth buffer.
- Keeping the camera lookat at (0,0,0).
- Panning rotating the planet instead of moving the camera.
- Scaling up or down the entire world.

---

This question most relates to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012352/strange-shaking-while-rotating-the-camera-with-orbit-controls-in-three-js) and I've modified that fiddle to better represent the core of my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/6qfaf5h0/

```
  for (var p = 0; p < mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array.length; p += 3) {
    var xyzPos = lonLatToVector3(0 + (((p / 3) % tileRes) / (tileRes - 1)) * anglePlane,
      0 + (parseInt((p / 3) / tileRes) / (tileRes - 1)) * anglePlane,
      0);

    mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[p] = xyzPos.x;
    mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[p + 1] = xyzPos.y;
    mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[p + 2] = xyzPos.z;
    //mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[p + 2] = 0; //<- uncommenting fixes shake but I need this axis
  }
```

I want a mesh with an anglePlane < 0.01 that (when zoomed in to a point where only a few vertices are visible) doesn't shake.

---

Other possibly helpful notes:

- Sprites don't shake despite using the same projection algorithm.
- In some cases even a zoomed in flat (elevation = 0) plane can look all wavy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might have to do with your scale too. Aren't you too 'small'?

Comment: @ValentinRoudge I think so. I've tried scaling up the planet but that doesn't seem to help. It may be that the more I scale up the planet the larger my tiles are but the farther they are from the origin which also causes the shake. What is the measure that is too 'small'?

Comment: For what it's worth, subtracting radiusOfPlanet from xyzPos.z seems to resolve the jittering. I'm not sure if that's helpful in the context of what you're trying to achieve however. Definitely an issue with floating-point precision and the number of significant digits you're trying to use.

Comment: @msun Actually, that was very helpful. It seems I need both the planet center and the lookat point on the surface to be at the scene's origin. Thanks! =)